# SQL: Joining 2 tables twice, same right side column

Tags: mysql, sql-server, select, join

SQL masters.

In my MySQL db there are tables like:

```
Users
----------------------------
UserID  | UserNickName | ...
(PK)    |              |     
----------------------------
1       | Lister       | ...
2       | Rimmer       | ...
3       | Kryten       | ...
----------------------------

Events
-----------------------------------------------------------
EventID | EventCreatedByUserID | EventEdittedByUserID | ...
(PK)    | (FK Users.UserID)    | (FK Users.UserID)    |
-----------------------------------------------------------
1       | 1                    | 2                    | ...
2       | 2                    | 3                    | ...
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Using following query I can select event entries and user nicknames who created the event:

```
SELECT EventID, ..., UserNickName
FROM Events
   JOIN Users
      ON Users.UserID = Events.EventCreatedByUserID

i.e.
Event #1 | Lister
Event #2 | Rimmer
```

But how would the query to select event entries incl. both user nicknames who created and last editted the event look like?

```
i.e.
Event #1 | Lister | Rimmer
Event #2 | Rimmer | Kryten
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just chain your joins together.  You'll have to create an alias on the user tables though since you use it twice.

```
SELECT EventID, ..., CreateUser.UserNickName, EditUser.UserNickName 
FROM Events
JOIN Users CreateUser
ON CreateUser.UserID = Events.EventCreatedByUserID
JOIN Users EditUser
ON EditUser.UserID = Events.EventEditedByUserID
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
SELECT e.*, u1.UserNickName AS createdBy, u2.UserNickName AS EditedBy
    FROM Events e
    LEFT JOIN Users u1 ON e.EventCreatedByUserID=u1.UserID
    LEFT JOIN Users u2 ON e.EventEdittedByUserID=u2.UserID
    WHERE ... your additional clauses
```